# What do the abrahamic angels call God?

Tags: abrahamic-religions, angels

There are many names for God. (Yahweh, Adonai etc.)

By what name might the angels call God?

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it deals more with Christianity or Judaism and as such should be asked on Christianity SE or Mi Yodeya SE.

Comment: But this deals with the specific mythology of Christianity or Judaism. It doesn't deal with the specific *religious* parts of the abrahamic faiths

Comment: @KenGraham - Sites aren't mutually exclusive.  This may be on-topic on Christianity.SE (I'd have to take your word for it), but that does *not* make it off-topic here.

Comment: She prefers "Captain," but "ma'am" is acceptable in a crunch.

Answer (score 6):

I fear behind this question lie the translation used... Angels do not overspeak, that said. There is reference of them here and there, but they keep their angelic mouth shut.

Genesis 3-23/24 in king James translation

> 23 Therefore the Lord God sent him forth from the garden of Eden, to
>   till the ground from whence he was taken. 24 So he drove out the man;
>   and he placed at the east of the garden of Eden Cherubims, and a
>   flaming sword which turned every way, to keep the way of the tree of
>   life.

And that is the same passage in the New World Translation:

> 23 With that Jehovah God expelled him from the garden of Eʹden+ to
>   cultivate the ground from which he had been taken. 24  So he drove the
>   man out, and he posted at the east of the garden of Eʹden the cherubs+
>   and the flaming blade of a sword that was turning continuously to
>   guard the way to the tree of life.

And in the Jerusalem Bible:

> 23. So Yahweh God expelled him from the garden of Eden, to till the soil from which he had been taken. 24. He banished the man, and in front of the garden of Eden he posted the great winged creatures and the fiery flashing sword, to guard the way to the tree of life.

So trying to know how they are addressing God is merely problematic, because the various translators are not agreeing between them on the name of God, far from.
That said, we have that is Tobias 12-15, I keep using King James translation only:

> I am the angel Raphael, one of the seven who stand before the Lord.

Another Angel talking in Matthiew, this time he uses Holy Spirit:

> "Joseph, son of David, do not fear to take Mary your wife, for that
>   which is conceived in her is of the Holy Spirit; she will bear a son,
>   and you shall call his name Jesus, for he will save his people from
>   their sins."

Same story in Luke:

> "In the sixth month, the angel Gabriel was sent from God to a town of
>   Galilee called Nazareth, to a virgin betrothed to a man named Joseph,
>   of the house of David, and the virgin's name was Mary." And coming to
>   her, he said, "Hail, Full of Grace! The Lord is with you."

In summary, there is Angelic references in the Bible but most of the time they do not talk and are either referenced or simply act as background characters. And when they do talk, they rarely use the name of God, and when they do the translators use a different name.
There is the high probability their is out there some hebraic/jewish books being more precise, but I do suspect those books would fall also in the category "depend the author".

Comment: That's what I'm hoping; for instances in lesser known texts of the angels referring to God. I know they say The Lord of Hosts in the Bible. Maybe they say something else in some other text, maybe not.